# Finding nth term of a sequence after typing the number in C

Tags: c

I have the following code that theoretically should compute value of an nth term of a sequence given by an equation where `a_0=1` and `a_(n+1)=a_n+1/k!`. I know that there is no factorial there, but with the exception of that, why is this code not working properly?

I want to type a number and then find the nth term of a sequence. I know it is not Fibonnaci even though that is the name of the function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"

int Fibonacci(float n) {
  float F0 = 1;
  float F;
  int i;

  if (n <= 1)
    return(n);

  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    F = F0 + pow(n, -1);
    F0 = F; 
    n+1;
  }
  return(F);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  float k;
  printf_s("numebr:\n");
  scanf_s("%d", &k);
  printf("Fibonacci(%d) = %f\n", k, Fibonacci(k));
  return(0);
}
```

How to create a better algorithm for this type of sequence i.e. the sequence mentioned at the begining?

Comment: Just fyi, you may want to fix the `%f` being used as the printf format for a function returning an `int` value.

Comment: @Krowskir well what did your introductory C tutorial say?

Comment: `float k; ... scanf_s("%d", &k);` is wrong as also is about 6 other things.  Some of these, the compiler should be warning about and others are more subtle.  Re-write your code so it, at least, provides no compiler warnings - re-post code with the warning if that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an int, but you want to return a float.
It should be:

`float Fibonacci(int n)`

instead of:

`int Fibonacci(float n)`

Comment: No i have " Error 2 error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function "

Comment: Hmmm "ambiguous call to overloaded function" Sounds like code is using a C++ compiler.